# Ajuda com UPDATE em lógica utilizando queries

Tags: php, mysql, query, select

É o seguinte galera, eu tenho duas tabelas, a tabela `esc_usuarios` que contém informações de usuários cadastrados e `esc_usuarios_slog`, que contém os registros das baixas, na qual são realizadas através de um botão que altera a coluna `usu_situacao` para `ativo`.

O que eu quero é criar uma função onde, se não tiver nenhuma baixa nos últimos 30 dias, o usuário é definido como `inativo`.

esc_usuarios:

```
 ________________________________
|usu_codigo|usu_nome|usu_situacao|
|----------|--------|------------|
|    32    |  Diogo |   ativo    |
|________________________________|
```

esc_usuarios_slog: `usu_slog_codigo` é o id do usuário

```
 ________________________________________________________
|usu_slog|usu_slog_codigo|usu_slog_data|usu_slog_situacao|
|--------|---------------|-------------|-----------------|
|    4   |      32       |  2018-10-08 |      ativo      |
|________________________________________________________|
```

O que eu tenho por enquanto é a query que procura se há baixas nos últimos 30 dias:

```
SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios_slog 
WHERE usu_slog_data 
between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE() 
ORDER BY usu_slog_data DESC
```

E também a que faz o `UPDATE` para `inativo`:

```
UPDATE esc_usuarios SET usu_situacao = 'inativo'";
```

Essas duas queries são tratadas dentro de if e else if.
Daí eu preciso dar esse update nos usuários que não tiverem uma baixa na tabela `esc_usuarios_slog`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode atribuir o resultado da *query* que procura se há baixas nos últimos 30 dias a uma variável. Sendo assim, você pode usar a função *mysqli_num_rows*, fazendo uma condição, que se tiver mais de 0 (zero) registros, você faz um loop nas baixas e executa a *query* que atualiza o status para cada usuário, usando como condição o código do usuário.

Exemplo:

```
$baixas = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios_slog 
WHERE usu_slog_data 
between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE() 
ORDER BY usu_slog_data DESC");

// aqui verifico se foi retornado alguma baixa
if(mysqli_num_rows($baixas) > 0) {
   // aqui percorro a lista de baixas retornadas
   foreach ($baixas as $baixa) {
       // aqui executo a query passando a condição WHERE
       mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE esc_usuarios SET usu_situacao = 'inativo' WHERE usu_codigo = " . $baixa['usu_slog_codigo']);
       // perceba que estou acessando o atributo usu_slog_codigo como array, para exemplo, vai depender de como você está retornando no seu, caso seja objeto, o acesso deve ser assim: $baixa->usu_slog_codigo
   }
}
```

Coloquei esse exemplo pra entender como funciona, aí só adaptar para como está fazendo.

Comment: Eu já fiz o tratamento com if e else, o problema é ele atualizar os usuários corretos.

Comment: Preciso saber como inserir um where aí onde só vai ser atualizado pra inativo, os usuários que não tiverem baixa, na minha query e na sua, ele vai atualizar todo mundo pra inativo

Comment: Entendi. Faz assim, se retornar algum resultado na query de baixas, faça um foreach nas baixas, e em cada loop você executa o comando de update, passando o código do usuário. Irei editar minha resposta para que veja